# React - Using Router for Dynamic URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

i'm creating a blog-type website in which the user clicks on an image and is then redirected to the blog post for said image. I wanted to know how to make it so that the url is "www.example.com/post1/" as opposed to "www.example.com/post/post1". I currently have this as my code which returns data from my database into an array and shows every post's first image in a clickable list element.

```
<li className='rounded flex-1 max-w-5xl'>
    <Link to={'/'+props.post.title} >
        <img className='mt-2' style={{width: "1000px", height: "667px"}} src={props.post.images[0]} alt="Test"/>
    </Link>
</li>
```

How would I make it so that whenever the link is clicked, the blog post component is loaded within the link?

Comment: Have a look at url parameters, you'll need your route to be something like <Route path="/:id />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your router switch something like this

```
  <Switch>
        <Route path="/:id"><Component /></Route>   
        {/* ... other routes ... */}
  </Switch>
```

And add these in your `Component`

```
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
//...
const Component = (props) => {
  let { id} = useParams();
  console.log(id)
  // write logic for utilizing `id`
  //...
  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Hope this helps